# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm new at C# and i can't understand why i'm getting this error. Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Window : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {

    WebServ.ItemDimWs con = new WebServ.ItemDimWs();

    decimal length, width, height, weight, rescode;
    string user, article, res;

    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        length = Convert.ToDecimal(tb_lenght.Text.ToString());
        width = Convert.ToDecimal(tb_width.Text.ToString());
        height = Convert.ToDecimal(tb_height.Text.ToString());
        weight = Convert.ToDecimal(tb_weight.Text.ToString());
        article = tb_article.Text;
        user = tb_user.Text;

        string result = con.setItemDims(article, length, width, height, weight, weight, "EA", "KG", "CM", user, ref rescode, ref res);
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        MessageBox.Show("Resp:" + rescode + res + "!!!");
    }
}
```

I need to send some info to the webservice and receive the answer.

Comment: con.setItemDims(..) is most likely a void function, which means it doesnt return anything, however your try to store it into the result string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebServ.ItemDimWs.setItemDims does not return anything, so you can't assign the output to a string.

So instead of doing this

```
string result = con.setItemDims(article, length, 
        width, height, weight, weight, "EA", "KG", "CM", 
        user, ref rescode, ref res);
```

You can go with

```
con.setItemDims(article, length, 
        width, height, weight, weight, "EA", "KG", "CM", 
        user, ref rescode, ref res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a return value of a method `setItemDims` to a string variable but the method is void (no return value)

Note: Not sure what are all the parameters of `setItemDims` bu I can see you are passing `ref res`, this might be a result being set. Again, Just guessing from the naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

Since the webservice method is not returning anything it cannot be called like this.

**string result = con.setItemDims(article, length, width, height, weight, weight, "EA", "KG", "CM", user, ref rescode, ref res);**

If you want the result to be output you can write service in such a way that result will be **out** parameter. (If you have access over the web service code.)